# Bash: echo statement placed before exit code 1 does not run

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, github-actions

```
if [ $GRADE -lt 7 ]; then
  echo "rating=failure" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  exit 1
    
else 
  echo "rating=success" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  exit 0
fi
```

I have a simple usecase wherein,

1. if the variable `GRADE` is less than 7, I want to ouput the value from `GITHUB_OUTPUT` and exit with a status code so that the GitHub action using this bash file will fail.
2. else I want to output the value and exit without the action failing

Comment: What do you mean by that it "does not run"? BTW, what is the point of setting the output parameter if it's going to fail in the next line?

Comment: @Azeem what I mean that the GITHUB_OUTPUT doesn't get any value, also I want to set the exit code 1 so that the GitHub action fails

Comment: How do you verify `GITHUB_OUTPUT`? How are you using that Bash snippet in your workflow? Please include this in your question. That would be helpful to understand your complete use case.

Comment: the GITHUB_OUTPUT will be used by the following Github step, The bash snippet is a part of a Docker Action

Comment: IIRC, and given that `GRADE`, you asked a question about https://securityheaders.com/ action (docker based) which was not working. And, I wrote this composite action (https://github.com/iamazeem/security-headers-action) so that it can be used on all GHA runners. So, now you're writing your own Docker action, is that right?

Comment: The echo statement **does** run. But unless `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` references a file, assigning a value to a variable in this way isn't going to work.

Comment: If you want to assign a value to variable `GITHUB_OUTPUT` then *do that*.  Assignments involve the `=` operator.  For example, `GITHUB_OUTPUT="rating=success"`.  Do also note that in the shell language, the `$` symbol specifies expansion.  It can be considered an operator.  It is not part of variables' *names*.

Answer (score 1):

> echo statement placed before exit code 1 does not run

Not plausible.

You clarify in comments that the actual observation is that variable `GITHUB_OUTPUT` does not receive a value, which is not the same thing at all.  And *of course* `GITHUB_OUTPUT` does not receive a value, because nothing in the script fragment presented would have that effect.

These commands ...

```
  echo "rating=failure" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  exit 1
```

... cause the `echo` command to attempt to write the text `rating=failure` to the **file** whose name is given by the current **value** of variable `GITHUB_OUTPUT`.  Nothing in them modifies the value of `GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

Moreover, even if that were what you wanted, there is a serious problem here in that because the expansion `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` is not quoted, you leave yourself open to several kinds of misbehavior:

1. If `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` expands to a value that contains multiple whitespace-separated words, then only the first will be taken as the destination filename.  The rest will be taken as additional data to output.
2. If `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` expands to nothing or to a value that contains only whitespace, then Bash will continue to the next line, taking `exit` as the name of the destination file, and `1` as additional data to output.

That explains why your script is not failing, but also not doing what you intend.

---

As a general rule, you should double-quote your variable expansions to avoid word splitting: `"$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`.  (On those occasions where you think you want the expansion to be word-split, you probably *really* want to use an array instead of a scalar variable.)  If you double-quoted the expansion in this case then you would probably see the script fail with a "No such file or directory" error, on account of the empty string not being a valid filename.

If you want to capture the output of a command in a variable, then use a command expansion: `$(the_command arg1 ...)`.  For example,

```
  GITHUB_OUTPUT=$(echo "rating=failure")
```

But that particular assignment is a bit ridiculous.  You don't need to `echo` or capture the string, because you can instead just assign it directly:

```
  GITHUB_OUTPUT="rating=failure"
```

---

Additional notes:

- as a matter of style and convention, do not use UPPERCASE for your script's internal variable names.
- Do not confuse the *name* of a variable, such as `GITHUB_OUTPUT`, with expressions designating the *expansion* of that variable, such as `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`.  There are languages in which some or all variable names must begin with a `$`, but in the shell language, the `$` is not part of the name at all.

  Sometimes you want the name, especially in assignments.  Other times you want the value.  You need to use the appropriate syntax in each case.